# what does '$::n' mean for perl?

Tags: perl

Do you know what "$::n;" means ? The section of codes is like below.

```
use JSON::XS;
# ...
open (YI, "| $cmd");
my $msg = { test => test };
my $emsg = encode_json($msg);
print YI "$msg_inject\n" unless $::n;
close YI;`
```

I remmeber that I also met $::v before.  What is $::v ? Does it have additional usage ?

I only know $: is reserved word for a perl statment with more lines being filling in a field.

Best regards,

TWLMD.

Comment: If you are responsible for this piece of code note that it has quite a few problems: two arg open and using a bareword to store the filehandle. See the new perlopentut in the current 5.19 development release for examples how to do it right.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$::n` is same as `$main::n` or just `$n` where $n is residing in `main::` package.

Such notation ignores eventual lexical (defined with `my`) definition of `$n`, ie.

```
perl -Mstrict -we 'our $n=3; my $n=1; print $::n'
```

output is `3`

Comment: (Interesting tidbit: `main::` is really just an reference to the empty namespace, so `$::n`, `$main::n`, `$main::main::n`, `$main::main::main::n`, etc are all the same var.)